# centos using older version of java

Tags: java

I want to install open office in my centos linux and as part of the requirement is jdk 11.0.2 version.

I installed new version of java JDK 11.0.2 however when I use the command java -version it is still showing that it is using old version of java.

```
java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_262"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_262-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.262-b10, mixed mode)
```

i created the file `/etc/profile.d/jdk11.sh` and ran the command below

```
"source /etc/profile.d/jdk11.sh"
```

the file contains

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-11.0.2
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using centOS:
try the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

It should show you the list of available Java versions in your system. You can switch using the numbers shown in the result of the command.